# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Section 3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi guys I'm just learning the tutorial and for some reason I am stuck on this part. I realize their might be changes since the tutorial was written.

It calls for generating static pages like so:

"rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework"

The command responds with...

C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>rails generate controller static_pages
C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `require': cannot
load such file -- active_resource/railtie (LoadError)
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.
/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.
/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in`'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in`'

---

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Tried bundle install with the same results. Here is application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
# If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
# If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
# Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SampleApp
class Application < Rails::Application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `bundle install`. If that does not work paste here your `config/application.rb` please.

Remember: You need Ruby 2.0.0 to use Rails 4

Upgrade to ruby 2 with RVM:

1. [Install RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)  `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`
2. Check `rvm get stable`
3. `rvm use ruby-2.0.0 --dafault`

Remember to specify in the top of your list the Ruby an rails version:

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> ruby '2.0.0'
>
> gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

Then run 'bundle install' again in your rails project and be happy.

Comment: I updated the question above with what my application.rb has.

Comment: Not sure if I have to change something in application.rb

Comment: Hi man! sorry I was busy. Important: I need your Ruby and Rails version. Use `ruby -v`and `rails -v` inside the project to check it.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 rails 4.0.2 No worries! Thanks for the help

Comment: OK Man. This is your problem. You need Ruby 2.0.0 to use Rails 4.

Comment: What do I have to do now?

Comment: No I just installed Pik